# What replacement token to use for counting a specific content-type

Tags: tokens

I have a content type of 'partners', and I wanted to create a body text like 'Currently we are working with X partners'. I have [token-filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) working, but I cannot find a token that allows me to choose the content-type.

`[content-type:node-count]` Doesn't do anything.

`[node:content-type:node-count]` Returns the amount of the current type (basic page, not partner).

Is there some token that allows me to choose the content-type to work with? eg. something like `[content-type:?:node-count]` where I can enter my content-type of partner on the `?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom module for this to calculate the specific amount of items. Now I can use a token like `[partner:partners]`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function partner_token_token_info() {
  $types['partner'] = array(
    'name' => t("Partner Tokens"),
    'description' => t("Tokens for partners."),
  );

  $partner['partners'] = array(
    'name' => t("Partners"),
    'description' => t("The count of partners."),
  );

  return array(
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => array(
      'partner' => $partner,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function partner_token_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'partner') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'partners':

          $query = db_select('node', 'n')
            ->condition('type', 'partner');
          $num_rows = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();

          $replacements[$original] = $num_rows;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```